# KVM: Cloning RHEL server on 2 disk images onto 1 disk image

Tags: disk-image

We currently have a RHEL VM that is running from 2 disk image files (excuse my terminology if it is incorrect). Is there a way of cloning these 2 disks to create a 1 disk image?

Comment: How do you make a physical machine with two hard drives have only one hard drive? You remove one. But then what do you do with the data?

The same is true of a virtual machine. You can remove a virtual disk, but you still must do something with the data on that disk.

Comment: Which hypervisor do you use?  You could create a multiple-disk OVA for transferring this VM, but the clone made from it would end up with 2 disks.